# BigQuery - Concatenate multiple rows and columns into a single row

Tags: google-bigquery

I have column like this

```
id|name | Country
1|John | usa
1|Tom  | Canada
1|Bob  | Italy
2|Jack | China
2|Tim  | USA
```

I need output like

```
id|Text
1| John USA , Tom Canada , Bob Italy  
2|Jack China, Tim USA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(name, ' ' , country)) text 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'John' name, 'Usa' country UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Tom', 'Canada' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Bob', 'Italy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jack', 'China' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Tim', 'USA' 
)
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(name, ' ' , country)) text 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

with output

```
Row id  text     
1   1   John Usa,Tom Canada,Bob Italy    
2   2   Jack China,Tim USA
```